# Naming different variables and using i to subset a file

Tags: r, loops, subset, assign

I want to go through a vector, name all variables with i and use i to subset a larger file.
Why this does not work?

```
x <- c(seq(.1,.9,.1),seq(.9,1,.01))

doplot <- function(y)
{
   for (i in unique(y))
   {
      paste("f_", i, sep = "") <- (F_agg[F_agg$Assort==i,])
   }
}  

doplot(x)
```

Comment: By "variables" you mean "values"?

Comment: Anyhow, I have no idea what you asking for, but maybe? `doplot <- function(y) {
 lapply(unique(y), function(y) paste0("F_", F_agg[F_agg$Assort == y, ]))
}`

Comment: Dear David, This way seem to work but the variables F_.1, F_.2 are not saved. I tried applying a return() but it also did not work.

Comment: In the end what is my problem. I want to subset a dataframe that contains 20 different values of $Assort and I want to store them with different names refering to the 20 different values.

Comment: Save the data with `temp <- doplot(x)` and then run `list2env(temp, .GlobalEnv)` and it will create your saparate data frames

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems here. First of all, on the left hand side of `<-` you need a symbol (well, or a special function, but let's not get into that now). So when you do this:

```
a <- "b"
a <- 15
```

then `a` will be set to 15, instead of first evaluating `a` to be `b` and then set `b` to 15.

Then, if you create variables within a function, they will be (by default) local to that function, and destroyed at the end of the function.

Third, it is not good practice to create variables this way. (For details I will not go into now.) It is better to put your data in a named list, and then return the list from the function.

Here is a solution that should work, although I cannot test it, because you did not provide any test data:

```
doplot <- function(y) {
  lapply(unique(y), function(i) {
    F_agg[F_agg$Assort == i, ]
  })
}
```

Comment: No it did not work. The data I have is simply a dataframe (F_agg) with one given column named Assort. Without the loop, I did:   F_.1 <- F_agg[F_agg$Assort==.1,]
F_.2 <- F_agg[F_agg$Assort==.2,]
F_.3 <- F_agg[F_agg$Assort==.3,]
F_.4 <- F_agg[F_agg$Assort==.4,]
F_.5 <- F_agg[F_agg$Assort==.5,]
F_.6 <- F_agg[F_agg$Assort==.6,] ... etc. Thanks, anyway. p.s. shouldn't I have a return F_i to save each file?

Comment: But as a result I have a LIST which contains all dataframes?

Comment: Yes, you have a list that contains all subsets. Don't you? It would actually be a lot easier if you supplied test data, then I could see what the input and the output are....